# mongoose validation matching an array with another array for common string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose Schema + validation

```js
var schemaInterest = new schema({

  active_elements: {
    type: [String]
    },

  pending_elements: {
  type:[String]
  }


});

schemaInterest.methods.matchElements = function matchElements() {
  this.find({active_elements: this.pending_elements}, function(){
    //shows all the matched elements
  });
};
```

I don't know how to work with error handling in mongoose yet. I want it so that if the elements match an error will be return if there is no match then the validation is successful. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that the arrays must contains all the same elements? At least one matching element? Something else?

Comment: at least one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the other property in your **[validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/validation.html)** by using `this.pending_elements` and comparing the arrays using the **[lodash](https://lodash.com/)** library's [**`_.isEqual()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) and [**`_.sortBy()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) methods:

```
var schemaInterest = new schema({  
    active_elements: {
        type: [String]
    },
    pending_elements: {
        type: [String]
    }
});

schemaInterest.path('active_elements').validate(function (v) {
    return _.isEqual(_.sortBy(v), _.sortBy(this.pending_elements))  
}, 'my error type');
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

From the OP comments (thanks to @JohnnyHK for pointing that out), at least one matching element, not the whole array is required thus you would need the [**`_.intersection()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) method which creates an array of unique values that are included in all of the provided arrays using `SameValueZero` for equality comparisons:

```
_.intersection(v, this.pending_elements)
```

would suffice. Thus your validation function would look like this:

```
schemaInterest.path('active_elements').validate(function (v) {
    return _.intersection(v, this.pending_elements).length > 0  
}, 'my error type');
```

Comment: According to the OP's comment, he's looking for at least one matching element, not the whole array. So `_.intersection(v, this.pending_elements)` should work.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Cheers for pointing this out, had missed that in the comments.